# How to avoid base64 in smtp email

Tags: powershell, smtp

I am sending emails using powershell and smtp. The email include a csv file as attachment. However, the attachment is being receiving with a base 64 format. How could avoid that?. I need to get the attachment in normal ASCII format

Comment: Post your code. We can't guess at how to fix the problem if we can't see how you're causing it. Are you using `send-mailmessage`?

Comment: It is very common for MIME encoded emails to use base64 encoding to encode an attached file.  Most mail clients are able to recognize and handle the base64 encoded file, and decode it properly.  If you are sending to a mainstream mail client, and the client is not handling it properly, then it probably means that your powershell script is not constructing the MIME messages properly.

Comment: I fix it. What I did was to use base64 to decode the attach. Thanks!!